# Saved 2.77 blender file opens up different

Tags: interface, blend-files

[image]
So recently (a few days ago) I've created a simple rendering using just a few wine glasses in Cycles Render.  I was happy with the results and saved my blender file.  Of course, it had the '.blend' extension.  When I loaded it up later my camera view looked all funky. I switched out of camera view and then back and then everything was fine.  Am I doing something wrong or is this an expected reaction to my blender file?  I saved it with the camera view pointing to the scene and it is a Cycles Render for v2.77.  It doesn't crash.  It simply looks weird when it comes up so I switch views and then come back and everything is good.  The inner gray area you see is the size of the camera view (Pressing 0).  By the way, it was in Camera View when saved.

Comment: Please add images of what "looks weird". It will be easier for us to help with more detailed information.

Comment: Added the screenshot I'm getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the UV/ image editor, change it back to the 3d view in the header below on the far left. [image]